# createDocsListDialog setInitialView error

Tags: google-apps-script

Back again with the createdocsListDialog function :)

I've got it working however, I'd like to limit the files to be selected to be only spreadsheets.

**"Error encountered: Cannot find method setInitialView(string). (line 13)"**

The .setInitialView appears in the script editor as a method, but when running.. not so much.  Here's the code.

`var doclisthandler = app.createServerHandler('selectionhandler');
var doclist = app.createDocsListDialog().showDocsPicker() .addSelectionHandler(doclisthandler).setInitialView('spreadsheet');`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the code completion itself you can see that the `setInitialView` function does not expect a string as parameter, but a FileType constant. On the [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_uiapp_filetypeconstants) you can see it is called `SPREADSHEETS`.

Here is how it works:

```js
app.createDocsListDialog().showDocsPicker().
  addSelectionHandler(doclisthandler).setInitialView(UiApp.FileType.SPREADSHEETS)
```

Comment: Henrique,  Thank you!   I had called the addSelectionHandler 'dosclisthandler'.  But it was the UiApp.FileType.SPREADSHEETS that did the trick !

Comment: Thanks ! How could we have guessed that the `FileType` enum was under UiApp ? The doc is so unclear...

Comment: @Offirmo the enums are always under the toplevel service of the function that expects them. But yes, UiApp documentation is not good.